# What is a simple command in RUBY to verify users input is and integer and not a string (no use of classes)?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, input, integer

I'm trying a rather simple program:

```
puts "Escriba un numero entero. Yo le diré si es par o impar. Si es impar,
    también le diré si es un multiplo de 3"

num = gets.chomp

if num == Integer
puts "well done"
end
if (num%2 == 0)
    puts "#{num} Es un número par"

elsif ((num%2 != 0) and (num%3 == 0))
    puts "#{num} Es un número impar y múltiplo de 3"

elsif ((num%2 != 0) and (num%3 != 0))
    puts "#{num} Es un número impar y no es multiplo de 3"
end

end

if num != Integer
    puts"Por favor intente con un numero entero"
end
```

However I want that in case the user tries with letters he gets a "try again" reply instead that conversion of the strings to numbers

Comment: try this condition, `num.between?(-(1/0.0),(1/0.0)) rescue false`, it finds whether the number comes between (-infinity, infinity). icould have used `num.is_a?(Fixnum)` but then the number could also become Bignum.

Comment: What do you mean with "no use of classes"? Every value in Ruby is an object, every object is an instance of a class. Almost every operation in Ruby either is or boils down to a method call, methods belong to objects (which are instances of classes) and are called on objects (which are instances of classes). It is literally impossible to do anything in Ruby without use of classes. Your own code sample uses *at least* 12 classes (`BasicObject`, `Object`, `Module`, `Class`, `String`, `Encoding`, `Integer`,`Fixnum`, `Bignum`, `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, and `NilClass`) and 1 mixin (`Kernel`).

Comment: A user input is always a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
num = '1234'
num == num.to_i.to_s #=> true

num = 'a123'
num == num.to_i.to_s #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression to detect a string containing only numbers:

```
if num =~ /\A\d+\Z/
   num.to_i # convert to i
else
   #...do non number stuff
end
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, `num.each_char.all? {|c| ('0'..'9').include? c}`, although the regex solution is better as long as you understand it.

Comment: While performance isn't mentioned as a factor, I would think this is quite a bit slower than the regexp